# MVC 3 - RouteUrl with 4 parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to build URL in razor view that will pass 2 RouteData.Values to my action.

This is the code:

```
<input type="button" value="View" onclick="location.href='@Url.RouteUrl("ViewMessage", new { threadId = 955, messageId = 11 })'" />
```

In Global.asax I defined the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"ViewMessage", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{threadId}/{messageId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Board", action = "Messages", threadId = UrlParameter.Optional, messageId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

);

Why my url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/Site/Board/Messages/955?messageId=11
```

and not like this:

```
http://localhost/Site/Board/Messages/955/11
```

I understand that I can use string.Format, but rather to find MVC helper solution

Answer (score 1):

try the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
"ViewMessage", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{threadId}/{threadId}/{messageID}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Board", action = "Messages", threadId = UrlParameter.Optional, messageId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be: if both `threadId` and `messageId` are optional, how would the following URL be resolved: http://localhost/Site/Board/Messages/955?

Try removing `UrlParameter.Optional` from `threadId` (and potentially using different route for that).

Comment: well, threadId is optional as well, but still it does included as route data

Comment: Does removing optional from `threadId` help? I can explain my opinion, but if it is wrong then there is no point.